# Raspberry Pi - Route not working when using "to: default" with netplan

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, netplan

I have installed Netplan on Raspberry Pi running "Raspberry Pi OS Lite", but while configuring static IP I encountered an issue.

This is the configuration I'm trying to apply, saved under `/etc/netplan/01-eth0-cfg.yaml`:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: false
      optional: true
      addresses:
      - 10.0.0.10/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 10.0.0.1
```

However, when running `sudo netplan apply` I get the following error:

```
(generate:5431): GLib-WARNING **: 08:45:13.605: GError set over the top of a previous GError or uninitialized memory.
This indicates a bug in someone's code. You must ensure an error is NULL before it's set.
The overwriting error message was: /etc/netplan/01-eth0-cfg.yaml:12:7: Error in network definition: unicast route must include both a 'to' and 'via' IP
      - to: default
      ^
/etc/netplan/01-eth0-cfg.yaml:12:13: Error in network definition: invalid IP family '-1'
      - to: default
            ^
```

Why isn't `to: default` recognized as a valid route?
It seems to work for a non-raspberry linux-box I have running. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem.

After reading the [article in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_route), I removed `default` from config file and used `0.0.0.0` instead. It looks like this:

```yaml
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.1.1
```

I am not an expert in networking and can't tell you if this is the right way. The only thing that I am sure is that the error goes away.

Don't forget the /0 at the end of the 0.0.0.0 that will route traffic bound to any ip not just 0.0.0.0